# Difference between Debug and Signing key

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, oauth-2.0

hi i am trying to get sign key MD5 finger prints for my signing certificate.can any one please tell the difference between sign key and debug key. i am able to fingure prints for debug key but for getting sign key finger print i am confused what is the meaning of my_release_key.keystore in keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore.
i am using the following link for getting signing key fingerprints.
 http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tutoral on signing your application:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

***About Signing in Debug Mode:***
The Android build tools provide a debug signing mode that makes it easier for you to develop and debug your application, while still meeting the Android system requirement for signing your .apk. When using debug mode to build your app, the SDK tools invoke Keytool to automatically create a debug keystore and key. This debug key is then used to automatically sign the .apk, so you do not need to sign the package with your own key.

***About Sign key:***
The Android system requires that all installed applications be digitally signed with a certificate whose private key is held by the application's developer. The Android system uses the certificate as a means of identifying the author of an application and establishing trust relationships between applications. The certificate is not used to control which applications the user can install. The certificate does not need to be signed by a certificate authority: it is perfectly allowable, and typical, for Android applications to use self-signed certificates.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani Can i locate the debug signing key in a folder?

Comment: Check "C:\Users\user\.android". what you're looking for is debug.keystore