# Google map api key Android release vs debug

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building an android app that uses Google Maps. Can I use my release key while I am in development?

Can someone explain the difference between the release and the debug keys?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7589382/792232 see here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The release key is produced using the `release.keystore` file that is produced when you sign you application to publish it to the market.

while the debug key is produces using the `debug.keystore` file that is generated when you compile your first project using eclipse.

AFAIK you can develop using the `release.keystore`.

Comment: Do I need to do something special to develop using the release.keystore?

Comment: I think it would be problematic because you signed you application right before you publish it to the market. this means that you will have a hard time testing your app.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you said. Is there any way that if I use eclipse, I press "run" and it uses the release.keystore? If I export my app, what do I do then?

Comment: AFAIK the answer is no. the problem is that you assign the release key only when you export you application to a signed .apk file. and this is not the apk file that produced to run your project on the AVD. So to check you application using the release key you would have to upload it to the market, download it using your phone and then test you map application. when you press the run button the apk file that is installed is not the signed one, and this is the reason why it would use the debug.keystore.

Comment: @Meir Why would you want to develop using release key?

Comment: I am periodically sending someone apk files for him to see updates, and I am trying to figure out the best way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: The best way would be to produce your release.keystore and create a Google API V2 for Android key using it. continue to develop you application using the debug.keystore and the API key you created using it. and before you send him the application just change the Google Map API key in the manifest file with the one you created using the release.keystore.

Comment: Of-course dont forget to produce a signed apk file from you project after you changed the key in the manifest file.

Comment: @Meir You may just send them APK signed with debug key (copy from project bin folder). Only make this additional step of signing with release key when it goes to the store.

Comment: Good idea, I had not thought of that at all!